# DeleteFile.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, listview, illegalargumentexception

I'm beginner and I apologize if this is too silly question. I try to create a filemanager. I want to realize deleting files with AlertDialog, but as a result of my efforts are unsuccesful.I post my last code.When I confirm deleting, occurs an error:794-794/standandroid.ru.filemanager

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /d contains a path separator
            at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:1672)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.deleteFile(ContextImpl.java:671)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.deleteFile(ContextWrapper.java:170)
            at standandroid.ru.filemanager.MainActivity$2$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:134)
            at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I understand that studio says that error in my parametrs, but i don't understand why they are wrong....Thanks in advance

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
private  String path;
private String selectedItem;
private final Context context=this;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);


    final ListView finalListView = listView;
    path = "/";
    if (getIntent().hasExtra("path")) {
        path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
    }
    setTitle(path);

    // Read all files sorted into the values-array
    List values = new ArrayList();
    File dir = new File(path);
    if (!dir.canRead()) {
        setTitle(getTitle() + " (inaccessible)");
    }
    String[] list = dir.list();
    if (list != null) {
        for (String file : list) {
            if (!file.startsWith(".")) {
                values.add(file);
            }
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(values);

    // Put the data into the list
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, values);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener itemLongClickListener=new       AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

           selectedItem=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
             final String filename = (String)       finalListView.getAdapter().getItem(position);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setMessage("Вы хотите удалить"+selectedItem+"?");
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Да", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


               deleteFile(path+filename);



        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Нет", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
    return true;
}};

 listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(itemLongClickListener);
    }
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    String filename = (String) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
    if (path.endsWith(File.separator)) {
        filename = path + filename;
    } else {
        filename = path + File.separator + filename;
    }
    if (new File(filename).isDirectory()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("path", filename);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, filename + " is not a directory", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deleteFile function cannot take a path, it can only take a filename with no separators (the path is assumed).  To delete a full path, create a File object for it and delete it through that object.

Comment: Also I tried to realize deleting with public void DeleteRecursive(String filename) {

            File file = new File(filename);
            if (!file.exists())
                return;
            if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                file.delete();
                return;
            }

            String[] files = file.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

                DeleteRecursive(filename + "/" + files[i]);
            }
            file.delete();


        }   But studio say that i have an error:NullPointerException